Why the patterned downvote on a correct Stack Overflow post answer?
A new contributor asked a fairly simple question and the answer was obvious. I always refrain from answering (mostly resorting to comments) unless I'm confident; then I post an answer.
I'm noticing somewhat of a pattern that whenever a post (mainly from a new contributor) has a downvote, the follow-up answers are always downvoted unless it's an answer posted by a user with high (say 1K+) reputation.
A recent example where I encountered this specific behavior is on this post. (By all means let me know if I have a bad answer.)
In a nutshell, the question is: how are new users encouraged to post questions/answers when this discouraging pattern persists?
Here are some other posts that would follow the mentioned pattern:

post0 - How to get user id in page route with NextJS : A beginner's question with a beginner's answer

post1 - Spring Boot-Thymeleaf redirect problem (When doing post request) : a beginner's question with a beginner's answer

post2 - Why is the initialization of this structure global variable wrong? : a beginner's question with an experienced user's answer.


And so on.

One post doesn't make for a pattern. Please provide multiple examples that actually show a pattern. I'm not saying one way or another as to if there's an issue, but vague statements about there being a pattern while providing only one example doesn't make for something that can be investigated.

The question you linked to got closed. Answering questions that are close worthy is will sometimes also lead to downvotes on answers. (no domain expert, I can't judge if the question should be closed)

The other answer not getting downvoted is easily explained by the fact that it's much more detailed... Rep has nothing to do with that.

My question still prevails. Why get a downvote on a correct answer regardless of the redundant/recycled question?

Some users downvote answers to questions that should be closed.

Your own actions indicate you feel the answer at post0 is bad, which invalidates it as an example here, as you already have determined a reason that it should be downvoted. I'm not saying you downvoted, as I don't have that information, but you have indicated you feel it's a bad answer, which inherently indicates that you feel the downvote was legitimate, presumably based solely on the post's content.

@Makyen im sorry but you're just trying hard to discard the reputation privilege im challenging (it's normal, given you're a top reputed account). The answer on post0 (at least in my opinion) is legit. In fact has my upvote which pushed it to -1 :)
Maybe redirect your energy on actually answering the question I asked previously in the comments?
Cheers

Asking why you get downvotes is not productive as it is not always answerable, people downvote for many reasons, and your new posts are not your questions/answers, so you have shown there is no pattern. Maybe redirect your energy on learning from the site and answer useful questions?

@Sarkis If you felt the answer was legit, why did you raise a Not An Answer flag on that answer? Raising a Not An Answer flag means you feel that the answer isn't an answer, which, effectively, means you feel it's worth a downvote. There were no upvotes on that answer when I wrote my comment. The only upvote on that answer was at 17:43:41 today, so your comment at 17:32:41 that you had upvoted is, in fact, a lie, which you may have corrected 11 minutes after posting your comment. As to the rest of your comment, you will find life better if you don't engage in unfounded, biased assumptions.

Sarkis, you're trying very hard to see a pattern here that somehow indicates higher rep users get away with posting bad answers... That's simply not the case. Higher rep users are generally held to a higher standard, are expected to know how the site works, and are more easily downvoted for bad answers. The fact that you completely discard Makyen's comment here seems to indicate you're not interested in people that disagree with you... Makyen has a lot of experience with SO, but you discard him just because of a (moderately, tbh) high rep count...

What do you define as "correct" here exactly? Simply an answer that provides a working solution to the question asked? Questions on-topic are rarely as black and white as having a "correct" answer; it's not like mathematics, where the correct answer to "What is 7+2?" is "9". There are many way to skin a cat.

The only a bit irregular "pattern" I notice, is that the Answerer to the 2nd Question (Qt) in the list (the "Java Spring Boot Thymeleaf" Qt) has a "tendency" to pick up low quality and easy to answer Qt's from the 'Staging Ground' and to approve them as quick as possible (while those should never have graduated to 'Main' in their current state) to be able to answer them in a FGITW-way within [1-3] minute(s) after approving them. (Instead of properly reviewing those Qt's in the 'SG' and improving them + checking for Duplicates if they have domain knowledge.) True for their last 3 Answers.

People with high reputation tend to write good answers. That's why they have the high rep. I suspect what you're observing is the obvious consequence of that, and nothing more.

@Sarkis - “Why get a downvote on a correct answer regardless of the redundant/recycled question?” - Do you have an example of a few of these answers? Specifically a high quality answer, which received downvotes, to a poor low quality question. Two of your examples in this question are not the greatest of examples of high quality answers. Let’s call a spade a spade, those answers are low quality not because how new the author is, but due to the distinct lack of quality.

The author of the first answer example as earned 8 reputation from their answer rather than 10. If you feel it’s a high quality answer. You should upvote it.

The most important thing you need to understand here is that Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum.
Users do not make "posts" here (except as a term to consider questions and answers collectively.) They ask questions and provide answers.
There are no "follow-up answers" - there are only answers. Because the "post" at the top is a question, which by its nature explicitly solicits an answer. That's not "following up", but answering. Answers do not reply to other answers. They only answer the question.
A question does not generically seek help with a problem. It asks something.
An answer does not address the OP or make general suggestions about learning the technology. It answers the question.
Downvotes have nothing to do with who posted content. They are rating the content.
Content is not rated according to people finding it entertaining or informative or ideologically agreeable or anything else that drives positive engagement on sites like Reddit. Questions are rated according to their ability to contribute to the site's purpose and goals. Answers are rated according to their ability to answer the question usefully, for everyone, not just the person who asked.
When a question doesn't contribute to what the site is trying to do,
answering it also naturally doesn't contribute to what the site is trying to do.
There is no need to "encourage new users to post". I did some quick database queries; almost half of new posts nowadays, including about 5/8 of questions, are from users with less than 100 reputation. Stack Overflow doesn't, in any way, suffer from a lack of content. If anything, it suffers from way too much content that is low quality and gets in the way of finding the actual good content. (Our content rating isn't always done properly, and external search engines don't understand it.)

Not sure if worth noting but there is some correlation between the author having higher reputation and their answers getting upvotes. However, often that's because  user with higher reputation is plain more skilled in writing answers. They would write answers where appropriate and would focus on making it a better answer. Newer users struggle with both of these - often answering things that shouldn't be answered and not providing as high quality content (e.g,, commenting in the answer box or only providing code-only solutions). These aren't strictly true always but still.

@VLAZ — I am more liberal with my votes when I encounter an answer from a user with a reputation.

"The most important thing you need to understand here is that Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum." – And the second most important thing you need to understand is that Stack Overflow is not a Question & Answer site either. It is a knowledge database which uses Questions and Answers as a vehicle to capture knowledge. Think Wikipedia, not Quora.

@JörgWMittag Quora might be the only "real" Q&A site in the sense you're describing.
